# How to display a custom alert dialog in Flutter based on Firebase Auth error message?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, alert

How to display a custom alert dialog based on an error message from Firebase Auth in Flutter. Let's say if a user submitted incorrect email or password or even user's email already registered on firebase then it will pop up an alert dialog based on it's error. Thank you in advanced

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you pleas provide your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `showDialog` method inside `catch`

```
  catch (e) {
          print(e);
          showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
            // set your custom alert dialog here 
            );
          });
  }
```